# Display aura "Map" type attribute results in a aura String attribute

Tags: aura

I'm working on an existing component that was passed on to me, and it stores some information in a map attribute type

```
<aura:attribute name="acct" type="Map" />
```

At one point, address information and name information gets populated into this map attribute type, and I need to be able to populate that information in an aura "String" type attribute.

The goal would be to have {!v.acct.address}, {!v.acct.phone}, {!v.account.name} to be stored in 3 individual String variables so that the information can be easily referenced in a Salesforce Flow.

Comment: What type of values are put in the map? Likewise, what's the process here - is a user entering info on an aura component that is later going into a flow?

Comment: @KrisGoncalves someone wrote a component  that grabs a business address location and business name from google maps but its stored in a map. I'm building a flow and need that information into the flow

Comment: How is it stored in the map? In terms of key-value pairing or if you have an example of a console output of a map in that component. I'm assuming the address/phone/name is all in that map?

Comment: @KrisGoncalves I'll be able to provide an example tomorrow morning, buy yes address/phone/name is all in the same map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have change handler on ***acct*** attribute so that whenever acct changes you can invoke a JS method load local field values. BUT because it is a Map type (type of javascript object), the change handler does not trigger without explicitly setting the ***acct*** - `component.set("v.acct", account)` in parent component (which somebody implemented).

You can implement as below in your component:

COMPONENT:

```
<aura:attribute name="acct" type="Map" />
<aura:attribute name="accPhone" type="String" />
<aura:attribute name="accName" type="String" />

<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.acct}" action="{!c.loadAccountFields}" />
```

CONTROLLER:

```
loadAccountFields : function(component, event, helper) {
    let acct = component.get("v.acct");
    component.set("v.accPhone", acct.Phone); // Phone should be exact property in acct - Case SenSiTiVe
    component.set("v.accName", acct.Name);
}
```

If you are getting `acct` on load itself, then you can also use ***init*** handler:

```
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.loadAccountFields}" />
```